# How to create update statement using results of sub-query where tables have same column name?

Tags: mysql

working on resolving issue where we need to update several thousand rows where there is an admin entity that isnt verified yet but there is a matching admin entity name in the verified list.

i have script written to pull the rows from that joins together the 2 tables. this gives me the list of rows that need update.

```
SELECT
pi.id AS `Primary Key for PI`,
pi.admin_entity_id,
pi.admin_entity_unverified,
asa.id AS `Admin Setup Accounts ID`,
asa.name AS `Admin Entity-Verified`
FROM
p_information pi
LEFT JOIN admin_setup_accounts asa ON asa.name = 
pi.admin_entity_unverified
WHERE
pi.admin_entity_unverified IS NOT NULL
AND pi.admin_entity_unverified <> ''
AND pi.admin_entity_id IS NULL
AND pi.admin_entity_unverified IN (select name  FROM 
admin_setup_accounts)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8c11a/3/0

This query returns list of unverified entries (pi.admin_entity_unverified) that match a verified list (asa.name) and the ID (asa.id) for each of those verified names.

i now need to do an update of all these matching rows and update the pi tables admin_entity_id with the corresponding admin setup accounts id (asa.id), so im thinking of doing like

```
update p_information pi
inner join (
SELECT
pi.id AS `Primary Key for PI`,
pi.admin_entity_id,
pi.admin_entity_unverified,
asa.id AS `Admin_Setup_ Accounts_ID`,
asa.name AS `Admin Auditing Entity-Verified`
FROM
p_information pi
LEFT JOIN admin_setup_accounts asa ON asa.name = 
pi.admin_auditing_entity_unverified
WHERE
pi.admin_auditing_entity_unverified IS NOT NULL
AND pi.admin_auditing_entity_unverified <> ''
AND pi.admin_auditing_entity_id IS NULL
AND pi.admin_auditing_entity_unverified IN (select name FROM 
admin_setup_accounts)) upi
ON upi.id = pi.id
SET pi.admin_entity_id = (this needs to be the asa.id AS `Admin Setup Accounts ID` returned from the subquery (upi)
```

but since pi and asa both use the id column inside the subquery how can i list those outside the query ? or is there another way to get this update done using the query? let me know

thanks

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: i think i have the solution mostly, im just trying to get how to finish the update statement since inside the subquery i have 2 columns as ID, and i need to reference both outside the query

Comment: i tried to add sql fiddle for the 2 tables and put link above, put in some fake data but not sure its working right, it is in my db, as i said what i need is to know how to differentiate the pi.id and asa.id inside the subquery when doing the update statement ?

Answer (score 0):

well i think i figured it out, i was thinking i couldnt use the column aliases outside the sub query, but it appears to work just fine. i do the set command as set pi.admin_entity_id = upi.Admin_Setup_ Accounts_ID and it updates correctly . :) oh well guess shouldnt overthink it